# How to remove all elements that match a certain condition except for N greatest of them with Stream API

Tags: java, sorting, optimization, java-stream, collectors

My question is: is there a better way to implement this task?

I have a list of orderable elements (in this example by `age`, the youngest first).
And I want to delete all elements that fulfill a *condition* (in this example *red elements*) but keep the first `2` of them.

```
Stream<ElementsVO> stream = allElements.stream();
Stream<ElementsVO> redStream = stream.filter(elem->elem.getColor()==RED).sorted((c1, c2) -> { return c1.getAge() - c2.getAge();
            }).limit(2);
Stream<ElementsVO> nonRedStream=stream.filter(elem->elem.getColor()!=RED);

List<ElementsVO> resultList = Stream.concat(redStream,nonRedStream).sorted((c1, c2) -> { return c1.getAge() - c2.getAge();
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Any idea to improve this? Any way to implement an accumulator function or something like that with streams?

Comment: Is the current implementation problematic? The problem with trying to do this "better" is that you would need a stateful filter (keeping track of the number of reds observed in the stream); but the documentation of `Stream.filter` says that filters should be stateless https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate).

Comment: In addition to what @AndyTurner said I would suggest using `.sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(ElementsVO::getAge))` instead of explicit lambda

Comment: You could write a List-collector that only collects the first 2 RED items

Comment: Sure it was working, but i just discovered the stream API and wanted to know if there were any ways of improvement that did not require, double streams like in my example.

Answer (score 2):

You can technically do this with a stateful predicate:

```
Predicate<ElementsV0> statefulPredicate = new Predicate<ElementsV0>() {
  private int reds = 0;

  @Override public boolean test(ElementsV0 e) {
    if (elem.getColor() == RED) {
      reds++;
      return reds < 2;
    }
    return true;
  }
};
```

Then:

```
List<ElementsVO> resultList =
    allElements.stream()
        .sorted(comparingInt(ElementsV0::getAge))
        .filter(statefulPredicate)
        .collect(toList());
```

This *might* work, but it is a violation of the Stream API: the documentation for [`Stream.filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) says that the predicate should be stateless, which in general allows the stream implementation to apply the filter in any order. For small input lists, streamed sequentially, this will almost certainly be the appearance order in the list, but it's not guaranteed.

Caveat emptor. Your current way works, although you could do the partitioning of the list more efficiently using `Collectors.partitioningBy` to avoid iterating it twice.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a **custom collector** that will maintain two separate collections of *RED* and *non-RED* element.

And since you need only two red elements having the greatest age to improve performance, you can introduce a **partial sorting**. I.e. collection of non-red element needs to maintain an order and always must be of size `2` at most, with that overhead of sorting will be far less significant in comparison to sorting of elements having the property of `RED` in order to pick only two of them.

In order to create a *custom collector*, you might make use of the static method [`Collector.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...)) which expects the following arguments:

- **Supplier** `Supplier<A>` is meant to provide a *mutable container* which store elements of the stream. Because we need to separate elements by color into two groups as a container, we can use a map that will contain only `2` *keys* (`true` and `false`), denoting whether elements mapped to this *key* are *red*. In order to store *red-elements* and perform a *partial sorting*, we need a collection that is capable of maintaining the order. `PriorityQueue` is a good choice for that purpose. To store all other elements, I've used `ArrayDeque`, which doesn't maintain the order and as fast as `ArrayList`.
- **Accumulator** BiConsumer<A,T> defines how to add elements into the *mutable container* provided by the *supplier*. For this task, the *accumulator* needs to guarantee that the queue, containing *red-elements* will not exceed the given size by rejecting values that are smaller than the lowest value previously added to the queue and by removing the lowest value if the size has reached the limit and a new value needs to be added. This functionality extracted into a separate method `tryAdd()`
- **Combiner** `BinaryOperator<A> combiner()` establishes a rule on how to merge two *containers* obtained while executing stream in parallel. Here, combiner rely on the same logic that was described for accumulator.
- **Finisher** `Function<A,R>` is meant to produce the *final result* by transforming the *mutable container*. In the code below, finisher dumps the contents of both queues into a stream, sorts them and collects into an immutable list.
- **Characteristics** allow fine-tuning the collector by providing additional information on how it should function. Here a characteristic `Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED` is being applied. Which indicates that the order in which partial results of the reduction produced in parallel is not significant, that can improve performance of this collector with parallel streams.

The code might look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<ElementsVO> allElements =
        List.of(new ElementsVO(Color.RED, 25), new ElementsVO(Color.RED, 23), new ElementsVO(Color.RED, 27),
                new ElementsVO(Color.BLACK, 19), new ElementsVO(Color.GREEN, 23), new ElementsVO(Color.GREEN, 29));
    
    Comparator<ElementsVO> byAge = Comparator.comparing(ElementsVO::getAge);
    
    List<ElementsVO> resultList = allElements.stream()
        .collect(getNFiltered(byAge, element -> element.getColor() != Color.RED, 2));

    resultList.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

The method below is responsible for creating of a collector that partition the elements based on the given *predicate* and will sort them in accordance with the provided *comparator*.

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> getNFiltered(Comparator<T> comparator,
                                                        Predicate<T> condition,
                                                        int limit) {
    return Collector.of(
        () -> Map.of(true, new PriorityQueue<>(comparator),
            false, new ArrayDeque<>()),
        (Map<Boolean, Queue<T>> isRed, T next) -> {
            if (condition.test(next)) isRed.get(false).add(next);
            else tryAdd(isRed.get(true), next, comparator, limit);
        },
        (Map<Boolean, Queue<T>> left, Map<Boolean, Queue<T>> right) -> {
            left.get(false).addAll(right.get(false));
            left.get(true).forEach(next -> tryAdd(left.get(true), next, comparator, limit));
            return left;
        },
        (Map<Boolean, Queue<T>> isRed) -> isRed.values().stream()
            .flatMap(Queue::stream).sorted(comparator).toList(),
        Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED
    );
}
```

This method is responsible for adding the next *red-element* into the priority queue. It expects a *comparator* in order to be able to determine whether the next element should be added or discarded, and a value of the maximum size of the queue (`2`), to check if it was exceeded.

```
public static <T> void tryAdd(Queue<T> queue, T next, Comparator<T> comparator, int size) {
    if (queue.size() == size && comparator.compare(queue.element(), next) < 0)
        queue.remove(); // if the next element is greater than the smallest element in the queue and max size has been exceeded, the smallest element needs to be removed from the queue
    if (queue.size() < size) queue.add(next);
}
```

**Output**

```
lementsVO{color=BLACK, age=19}
ElementsVO{color=GREEN, age=23}
ElementsVO{color=RED, age=25}
ElementsVO{color=RED, age=27}
ElementsVO{color=GREEN, age=29}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a generic Collector with a predicate and a limit of elements to add which match the predicate:

```
public class LimitedMatchCollector<T> implements Collector<T, List<T>, List<T>> {

    private Predicate<T> filter;

    private int limit;

    public LimitedMatchCollector(Predicate<T> filter, int limit)
    {
        super();
        this.filter = filter;
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    public Supplier<List<T>> supplier() {
        return () -> new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<List<T>, T> accumulator() {
        return this::accumulator;
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<List<T>> combiner() {
        return this::combiner;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Stream.of(Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH)
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
    }

    public List<T> accumulator(List<T> list , T e) {
        if (filter.test(e)) {

           if (count >= limit) {
               return list;
           }
           count++;
        }
        list.add(e);
        return list;
    }

    public List<T> combiner(List<T> left , List<T> right) {
        right.forEach( e -> {
            if (filter.test(e)) {

                if (count < limit) {
                    left.add(e);
                    count++;
                }
             }
        });

        return left;
    }

    @Override
    public Function<List<T>, List<T>> finisher()
    {
        return Function.identity();
    }

}
```

**Usage:**

```
    List<ElementsVO> list = Arrays.asList(new ElementsVO("BLUE", 1)
           ,new ElementsVO("BLUE", 2) // made color a String
           ,new ElementsVO("RED", 3)
           ,new ElementsVO("RED", 4)
           ,new ElementsVO("GREEN", 5)
           ,new ElementsVO("RED", 6)
           ,new ElementsVO("YELLOW", 7)
           );
    System.out.println(list.stream().collect(new LimitedMatchCollector<ElementsVO>( (e) -> "RED".equals(e.getColor()),2)));
```